# How to center align createMaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Currently my items are all to the left as they should be by default. I can not seem to move it to the center. For reference, I have attached an image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ2Eu.png

I have already tried styling it with tabStyle and using alignSelf: 'center' alignItems: 'center' flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center'

Here is the code:

```
export const FoodScreenNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    "McD": {
      screen: McDGrid,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "McD"
      }
    },
    "Subway": {
      screen: SubwayScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Subway"
      }
    },
    "BurgerKings": {
      screen: BurgerKingSelection,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Burger Kings"
      }
    },
    "ItalianMCT": {
      screen: StyleSelection,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Italian MCT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.FontColors.light_grey,
      inactiveTintColor: colors.FontColors.light_grey,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: colors.FontColors.dark_grey,
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      labelStyle: {
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: fonts.h5,
        fontFamily: fonts.OpenSansSemiBold,
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      tabStyle:{
        width: "auto"
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: colors.UiBgColors.light_red,
        borderBottomWidth: 4,
        justifyContent: "center"
      },
      upperCaseLabel: false
    },
    backBehavior: "none"
  }
);
```

package.json

```
"react-navigation": "^4.0.8",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.9.0",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding marginLeft in tab style like

```
tabStyle:{
        width:"auto",
        marginLeft:3,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trying, this configuration for screenOptions finally worked for me:

```
        tabBarContentContainerStyle: {
          width: 'auto',
          minWidth: '100%',
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
        },
```

It was also necessary to remove "tabBarIndicatorContainerStyle" and to set "tabBarScrollEnabled: false".

I hope it helps anyone.